find if everything in a list between two indexes is equal to "empty" in python
I am working on a game in PyGame and I only want an enemy to move if all spaces between them and the player are "empty". the board is basically just a list:
occupants = ["enemy", "empty", "enemy", "empty", "empty", "player", "empty"]

in this position I only want the second enemy, on index 2, to move, because all spaces between index 2 and index 5 are "empty. How do I check this?

in this example it would end up with occupants = ["empty", "enemy", "empty", "enemy", "empty", "player", "empty"] after a turn in which the player did not move

what I see in your comment is that every element of the array moves one index up in the array, the first element becomes an empty and between the enemy and the player the is one empty less? Is that okay?

Did you try solving it using a loop and get anywhere that felt closer to a solution?

Start at the player:
player_index = occupants.index("player")

Find the first thing to the left that isn’t empty, if there is anything:
nonempty_index = player_index - 1

while nonempty_index != -1 and occupants[nonempty_index] == "empty":
    nonempty_index -= 1

If it’s an enemy, move it to the right:
if nonempty_index != -1 and occupants[nonempty_index] == "enemy":
    if nonempty_index + 1 == player_index:
        raise NotImplementedError("TODO: handle enemy next to player")

    occupants[nonempty_index + 1] = "enemy"
    occupants[nonempty_index] = "empty"

Repeat on the other side.

Another way: make one pass over the list, keep track of the last non-empty thing you saw and where it was, and take action when appropriate.
def move_by(occupants, i, d):
    if i + d < 0:
        raise ValueError(f"Tried to move {occupants[i]} past left edge")
    if i + d >= len(occupants):
        raise ValueError(f"Tried to move {occupants[i]} past right edge")
    if occupants[i + d] != "empty":
        raise ValueError(f"Tried to move {occupants[i]} into {occupants[i + d]}")

    occupants[i + d] = occupants[i]
    occupants[i] = "empty"


last_nonempty, last_nonempty_index = None, None

for i, x in enumerate(occupants):
    if x == "empty":
        continue

    match last_nonempty, x:
        case "enemy", "player":
            move_by(occupants, last_nonempty_index, 1)
        case "player", "enemy":
            move_by(occupants, i, -1)

    last_nonempty, last_nonempty_index = x, i


This should solve your problem. The function takes your list of occupants as input and returns that list but with the closest enemy moved one step to closer to the player.
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def move_enemy(occupants: list) -> list:
    player_idx = occupants.index("player")
    enemy_indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(occupants) if x == "enemy"]
    closest_enemy = min(enemy_indexes, key=lambda x: abs(x - player_idx))

    distance = player_idx - closest_enemy
    left_or_right = int(distance / abs(distance))

    occupants[closest_enemy], occupants[closest_enemy + left_or_right] = (
        occupants[closest_enemy + left_or_right],
        occupants[closest_enemy],
    )

    return occupants


if __name__ == "__main__":
    occupants = ["enemy", "empty", "enemy", "empty", "empty", "player", "empty"]
    print(move_enemy(occupants))

